# Redirection code not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with my role redirection. Why my code

```
 {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Adminstrator"))
            Response.Redirect("~/4_Admin/Page1.aspx");
        else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Users"))
            Response.Redirect("~/3_User/Expense.aspx");
    }
```

is not working? It give me a headache after I spent like what, 3 days? Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Should that be `Administrator`?

Comment: I would like to thank to all of you here for helping me aolving all my questions here. My lecturer just came visit me here, and she praised my works. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The role "Adminstrator" is missing the letter **i** - add that in and the first branch of the IF statement should start working.

Answer (score 0):

i have some suggestions,

1) first check ur conditions are correct.
2) debug the code and try to get any exception or not
3) if you are using try catch use response.redirect("path",false);
4) if you are hosting your application inside iis check your application virtual path.
   while hosting your application if your application is sub website of something else
   it will cause 404 error.